# Creating a notification with BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to create a notification using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver. ( API 19, KitkKat)

I am following steps tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gm5n_hRIR-c
(Starts at 10:51)

But I can not get the application to work. No throw notification. :/
Help, here is my code.

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button btnN = ( Button) findViewById(R.id.btnalarm);
btnN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Long alertOfTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 5 * 1000;

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, Alert.class);

    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alertOfTime,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,alertIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

       }
    });
}
```

My class Alert

```
public class Alert extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          createNotification (context,"NATURE TIP","When","Alert");

}

 public void createNotification (Context context ,String msgg ,String msgAlert,String msgText){
PendingIntent pendIntentTwo = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,
            new Intent(context,MainActivity.class),0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tree_24_24)
            .setContentTitle(msgg)
            .setTicker(msgAlert)
            .setContentText(msgText);

 mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendIntentTwo);

    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

NotificationManager nNotifManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);//

    nNotifManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Mi MainLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backk">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alarm Notif"
    android:id="@+id/btnalarm"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Manifiest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARMY"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="App Nature"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    >
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="App Nature" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Your alert class is not in the manifest, you need to add that `<receiver
            android:name=".ui.activity.Alert"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">`

Comment: I think you're right, thanks. But I want to ask, because when I think the Alert class, not the .XML is created?
For this reason, I could not include it in the Manifiest.                   PD (I am new to android) @Drdavidpier

Comment: You just need your alert class listed in the manifest. Your XML does not need to be in there. Don't copy my code exactly as I don't know your file paths etc but you can use as a template.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't register the broadcast in your manifest. That's why it is not working . Broadcasts must be registered before use. So first register your class alert in your manifest and if you are using any action then also declare action in you manifest file using intent filter.